# Problema al calcular la diferencia entre dos fechas en SQL Server

Tags: sql

necesito ayuda con una funcion ya que se encarga de calcular la diferencia de años, meses y dias que hay entre dos fechas

pero resulta que no los calcula de forma precisa y la verdad para la operacion que deseo aplicar debe ser precisa.

por ejemplo si la consulta estuviera bien deberia devolverme
"2 año, 8 meses y 12 días".
pero me devuelve "2 año, 8 meses y 9 días".

```
WITH cteMeses AS (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN '2023-11-01' < '2021-02-20' THEN 0
            WHEN DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '2021-02-20', '2023-11-01'), '2021-02-20') >= '2023-11-01' THEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, '2021-02-20', '2023-11-01') - 1
            ELSE DATEDIFF(YEAR, '2021-02-20', '2023-11-01')
        END AS años,
        CASE
            WHEN '2023-11-01' < '2021-02-20' THEN 0
            WHEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2021-02-20', '2023-11-01'), '2021-02-20') > '2023-11-01' THEN (DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2021-02-20', '2023-11-01') - 1) % 12
            ELSE DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2021-02-20', '2023-11-01') % 12
        END AS meses
)

SELECT
    años,
    meses,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, '2021-02-20', DATEADD(MONTH, -meses, DATEADD(YEAR, -años, '2023-11-01'))) AS dias
FROM cteMeses;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre encontrar solucion al problema
aqui lo dejo resulto por si alguien mas tiene el mismo inconveniente que yo

```
  WITH cteMeses AS (
        SELECT
            DATEDIFF(YEAR, '2022-02-20', '2023-10-31') - 
                CASE WHEN 
                    MONTH('2023-10-31') < MONTH('2022-02-20') OR 
                    (MONTH('2023-10-31') = MONTH('2022-02-20') AND DAY('2023-10-31') < DAY('2022-02-20')) 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS años,
            (12 + MONTH('2023-10-31') - MONTH('2022-02-20') - 
                CASE WHEN DAY('2023-10-31') < DAY('2022-02-20') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) % 12 AS meses
    )
    
    SELECT
        años,
        meses,
        CASE WHEN DAY('2023-10-31') < DAY('2022-02-20') THEN
            DAY(EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, '2023-10-31'))) + DAY('2023-10-31') - DAY('2022-02-20')
        ELSE
            DAY('2023-10-31') - DAY('2022-02-20')
        END AS dias
    FROM cteMeses;
```